# Clarification: Command which gem not showing the gem path correctly in m1 machine

Tags: terminal, big-sur, rvm

I am getting below snippet while running the **which gem** in my m1 mac machine

```
gem () {
    \typeset result
    (
        \typeset rvmrc
        rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc") 
        if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
        then
            rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc") 
        fi
        for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
        do
            [[ -s "${rvmrc}" ]] && source "${rvmrc}" || true
        done
        unset rvm_rvmrc_files
        command gem "$@"
    ) || result=$? 
    hash -r
    return ${result:-0}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Does the above is correct or not. In other machines it will show the version alone

Answer (score 2):

RVM installs "gem" as a shell function gem() instead of relying on a traditional executable. This is why you get the definition of that shell function displayed instead of a path to an executable.

Note that when you run "which" here, you're most probably actually getting the result of "whence" in a zsh shell.

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting this same output when I run in my default terminal (which is zsh). When I run the command in a bash shell, I get the expected output showing the path of the gem command.

By running `which which` in terminal (zsh), it shows that the `which` command is not doing what it does in bash.

So, a few options (all give identical output):

1. run `/usr/bin/which gem`
2. run `which -p gem`
3. run `whence -p gem`

I found options 2 and 3 from the accepted answer and comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719757/zsh-which-rvm-or-which-gem-returns-the-function-contents-instead-of-the-path/7733996#7733996)